# How should I write unit tests for a method uses timer?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've written a method that waits for 5 seconds, how should I write unit tests for it to ensure that it has waited for 5 seconds?

```
public IObservable<Unit> Wait(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var unit = Observable.Return(Unit.Default);

            lock (Locker)
            {
                if (Waited)
                    return unit;

                Waited= true; 

                unit = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                    .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                    .RunAsync(token);
            }

            return unit;
        }
```

Comment: (1) Take the current wallclock time. (2) Call the method to be tested. (3) Take the current wallclock time again. (4) Subtract the times; assert it's more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StopWatch` class to measure time or just take current time before and after the method is called and assert that 5 seconds or more passed.

For example:

```
using Shouldly;

var watch = StopWatch.StartNew();
Wait() // call your function
watch.stop();
watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ShouldBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo(5);
```

or

```
Assert.IsTrue(watch.Elapsed.Seconds> 5, "The time was not greater than five");
```

Comment: I've tried this and got zero instead of 5. Have any idea why?

Comment: add the code u tried to run so we can help any further

Comment: one thing that comes up even before showing your code is that this function `Wait` is asynchronous but it seems like you dont `await` it so the calling function (your test) finishes running before you finish waiting on your function